# jQuery - Drop down menu in sidebar how to stop it from auto opening when page loads

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, sidebar

New to the front end and I am using a jQuery drop down menu for my sidebar.

Problem is that the menu is already dropped down when a user loads the page.

How do I change this so it doesn't auto drop down when the page is loaded? (am getting a open/close effect when I click on different pages e.g., when I click somewhere it retracts up then when the page loads it drops again)

Also, when the drop is closed and re-open it POPS back to the top of the screen, is there anyway to change this to?

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Dropdown toggle
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="">2014</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">December 2014</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add CSS

```
.dropdown {
    display:none;
}
```

That way it is closed when opening a page and clicking on the `2014` link will show it.  Clicking anywhere else on the document closes it again. http://jsfiddle.net/VPJC2/1/

**Update**

To prevent the page scrolling to the top (which it does because `href="#"` and is trying to find an anchor which doesn't exist) you can modify your javascript by preventing the default for the click event.

```
//... Other code here
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
//... Other code here
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPJC2/1/

Comment: That works! Will accept it in 6 mins. How I can stop it from popping to the top of the page when the drop down is clicked?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand that part?! How does it 'pop' to the top of the page?

Comment: If the scroll bar is not on the top of the page, say I've scrolled down a few lines and I click on 2014 - the scroll bar pops to the top of the page. (the effect is like when you hit home key to go back to the top every time the drop down is clicked) If you're on the top of the page it's fine but if not it pops to the top.

Comment: Hmm when I try this the drop down no longer works. I am actually using href="" `<a href={{ path('acme_demo_page_archive', { 'year': '2014', 'month': 'December' }) }}">`

Comment: What HTML does that output *exactly*?  I guess it's missing the class `dropdown-toggle`

Comment: Sorry, href is still href="#". (was confused with the <li> tag anchor before) The page output is `<a style="text-decoration:none" class="dropdown-toggle" href="" title="">2014</a>`

Comment: Nevermind it works, was a copy/paste fail apparently! Thank you Rob! You sir, ROCK!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the submenu by adding a style tag or you can hide the submenu when the document has loaded.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Dropdown toggle
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dropdown-toggle').next('.dropdown').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

You can also manually hide the submenu with a style tag like

**HTML**

```
 <a style="text-decoration:none" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="">2014</a>
 <ul class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
     <li style="list-style-type: none"><a href="#">December 2014</a></li>
 </ul>
```

You are using the .click() handler correctly. It doesn't initiate a click event ( http://api.jquery.com/click/)

**EDIT**: Corrected my HTML